# Confusion over manual/automatic sizing of Flash Sprite Objects

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

If I have a custom class subclassing `Sprite` and it draws some simple objects, how does this work with respect to the `Sprite.width` & `Sprite.height` properties? It seems I can draw (for example) a rectangle of any size, bigger than the Sprite size.
Similarly if I set the width/height properties, what happens to the content already drawn?

As a use-case, I might have a stick-man which is drawn as a set of lines, I want to set the man's height and the rendering is scaled to this.

*Are* there any issues with width/height being auto-calculated or am I misunderstanding what these properties actually *mean*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`width` and `height` make much more sense as getters. They take the internal content of the clip, multiply it by scaleX/scaleY and return it.

Internally the clip's scaling is stored as a matrix, and you can access individual elements of the matrix with the `scaleX` / `scaleY` properties (as well as `x`, `y`, and `rotation`).

You can also *set* `width` and `height` and there's some slightly awkward code that runs behind the scenes to make it work. Basically, whatever width you set is immediately turned into a `scaleX` value. For example if you have a 100x100 movieclip, and call `width = 200`, Flash will translate that to `scaleX = 2`.

If then, in the course of its animation, the movieclip grows to 120x100, then it will appear on the stage with a width of 240.

In other words the width and height that you set are applied as scaling factors. It has nothing to do with clipping the content.

For maximum predictability, always set to the `scaleX` / `scaleY` values.

Comment: But how do you set (or how does Flash know) the _default_ size to apply scaling to? Say a simple class subclasses `Sprite` and draws just 2 circles at (20,20) and (80,20), both radius 20?

Comment: scaleX and scaleY are the masters here, and they default to 1. The width and height will automatically adjust to whatever the content is. (Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "default size to apply scaling to").

Comment: By default I meant "what width/height will report if I don't change anything?" I think you answered this... they are auto-calculated based on content? So in my example above width = 100 height = 40?

Comment: Yep. You might want to just play around with some timeline code in a blank fla, and see what happens to different sprites when you mess with the different properties. It gets weird when you stick rotation in there too :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you are bit confused. Whatever is drawn in the Sprite will be resize too when you change the width, height, scaleX or scaleY.

There is an important concept of nesting of DisplayObjectContainers:

Let's say you have a **parent** Sprite that contains **child** Sprite that has a stick-man drawing 100 pixels high and wide. The *width*, *height* of both **parent** and **child** are 100 (while *scaleX* and *scaleY* are 1). Now if you set the *width* of **parent** to 50 px, the drawing on stage will be visually distorted, it will look like 50 px wide, the *width* of **parent** will be 50 px but *width* of the nested **child** will be still 100 px. Similarly the *scaleX* of **parent** will be 0.5 while *scaleX* of **child** will stay 1. Makes sense?

Comment: So does this mean I can't use `height * 0.5` when drawing lines that make a stickman, would this cause some circular calculation since `height` would get recalculated after drawing?

Comment: Lets say you have `myCanvas:Sprite` and use the `draw()` function to draw a stickman. Then you set `myCanvas.height = myCanvas.height*0.5` (what is equal to `myCanvas.scaleY = 0.5`). The points of your stickman won't be affected, the (100,100) point will be still on (100,100) coordinate, what has changed is the myCanvas size in it's parent container. So, the points of your stickman won't bet recalculated, you have changed the convas.

Comment: @John: Yes, that's right, if you try to use a clip's `height` as you draw into it, it will continually change, however the classic solution is to draw the lines at a set size and scale the containing clip as appropriate.